# Publishing Java Plugin to Repo error

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to publish my plugin to the pluginrepository on OSS-SonaType. They have already provisioned my namespace for both snapshots and full releases. I am struggling to make my first initial commit to the repo. I can't seem to find the right Maven Configuration to push the plugin to the repo rather than trying to update the repo. Below find my pom.xml, and maven configuration code. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Pom.xml:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.companynamehere.dmweb</groupId>
  <artifactId>DMWeb</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>DMWeb</name>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>OSS-Repo</id>
            <name>oss-repo</name>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

**Maven Config:**

```
Goals: com.companynamehere:DMWeb:validate
```

**Error:**

```
Error resolving version for plugin 'com.companynamehere:DMWeb' from the repositories [local (C:\Users\kylec\.m2\repository), OSS-Repo (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)]: Plugin not found in any plugin repository -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: First follow the maven default layout...never define plugins in pom better use the `settings.xml` file for that and use a repository manager ...and i have my doubts that you really like to use snapshots in your build.

Comment: Hi @khmarbaise, can you provide some more information about this settings.xml and what the default maven layout is? Also this plugin is in beta status so I thought it would be better to publish as a snapshot?

Comment: One part of my sentence is simply wrong. `never define plugins in pom...` I meant: `never define properties in pom`...https://maven.apache.org/settings.html. If your plugin is in beta just make a beta release or use a version like `0.2.0` ...

Comment: @khmarbaise Ok I see, I can move my pluginRepositories and other properties to this settings file, but what would be the proper Maven commands to push the initial java bundle to the repo?